# Joomla extension, JomSocial: Removing the welcome email upon registration

Tags: email, joomla, registration

On Joomla! 2.5.4 I'm using the JomSocial 2.6.0 extension. Looking for the code that is sending the first registration notification email "welcome email containing username+password" so that I can remove it.

Currently there are two emails sent upon registration, the first which contains the username and password, second that contains the verification link. However I think that having two emails is totally unnecessary.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the code from com_community/controllers/register.php

```
$this->_sendEMail('registration_uncomplete', $tmpUser, $password);
```

Is it safe or a good idea to just null this?

```
//$this->_sendEMail('registration_uncomplete', $tmpUser, $password); 
$var = NULL;
```

seems to be working...